# Cron in docker container with django

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, cron

I have django project and make managment command for django. This command delete some objects from db. So If I run it manually "docker-compose exec web python manage.py mycommand" it works fine, but when I try add task into cron using crontab (cron located in django container):

```
*/1 * * * * path/to/python path/to/manage.py mycommand >> cron.log 2>&1
```

django raise:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Tasks without db connection work fine.
**Problem is that tasks executed by cron can`t connect to db. Any ideas how to change crontab file  or docker-compose.yml?**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/domspass
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.2
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - db.env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


volumes:
  postgres:
```

Comment: Hi @Artur, could you please show us the DB env variables from files `db.env.dev` and `.env.dev`?

Comment: .env.dev
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME=mydbname
DB_USER=mydbuser
DB_PASSWORD=pass

db.env.dev
POSTGRES_USER=mydbuser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
POSTGRES_DB=mydbname